# Compare values of 2 arrays, then use the keys of matched values to move files

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to set up a script that will move files from in a particular directory to a specific subdirectory, depending on the prefix of the filename.

As it stands, I have two arrays, one set out as such:

```php
$arr1 = array(

[12] => "prefix1", 
[34] => "prefix2"
)
```

etc etc, where the keys are user IDs from our database, and the values are the prefix of that user's email address.

The other is like so:

```php
$arr2 = array(

["prefix1_filename.ext"] => "prefix1",
["prefix2_filename.ext"] => "prefix2"
)
```

And so on.

These arrays will not be the same length.

What I want to do is compare the two arrays, and where a value in arr1 matches a value in arr2, take the corresponding keys and push those to a new array that looks like this:

```php
$arr3 = array(

[12] => "prefix1_filename.ext",
[34] => "prefix2_filename.ext"
)
```

This will then be used to move the files into a subdirectory named for the id - eg /foo/bar/12/prefix1_filename.ext, /foo/bar/34/prefix2_filename.ext etc etc.

I've tried using array_combine, but as the two are not the same length, an error results. I've also tried intersecting them, to no avail.

Can anyone point me towards a solution that will achieve this? I can flip the arrays to make the keys the values if that will make this simpler.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `[12] => "prefix1",` <-- should this be `prefix` or should `["prefix_filename.ext"] => "prefix",` be `prefix1`?

Comment: Have changed the examples so it's consistently prefix1 where before it was a mix of prefix and prefix1

Comment: use `array_flip()` and match keys

Comment: Doing this unfortunately outputs the values from arr1 and arr2 as key => value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, with a bit of trickery.

First of all, let's take the values from $arr1 that are present in $arr2:

```
$isect1 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

Then, get the opposite

```
$isect2 = array_intersect($arr2, $arr1);
```

Now we have keys from both arrays, but we want to sort them to ensure they're in the same order. We'll need to flip them first.

```
$sorted1 = array_sort(array_flip($isect1));
$sorted2 = array_sort(array_flip($isect2));
```

Now we have that, we can just combine them back

```
$arr3 = array_combine(array_values($sorted1), array_values($sorted2));
```

Demo out of the way, to cut down on the variable copying, we can do it in one line:

```
$arr3 = array_combine(array_values(array_sort(array_flip(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)))), array_values(array_sort(array_flip(array_intersect($arr2, $arr1)))));
```

Phew. Got there in the end!

**EDIT**

Here's my Psy Shell output testing this, added some extra "non matching" values in to test the filtering:

```
>>> $arr1 = [12 => "prefix1", 34 => "prefix2", 99 => "some_other_prefix"];
=> [
     12 => "prefix1",
     34 => "prefix2",
     99 => "some_other_prefix",
   ]
>>> $arr2 = ["prefix1_filename.ext" => "prefix1", "prefix2_filename.ext" => "prefix2", "another_prefix_filename.ext" => "another_prexix"];
=> [
     "prefix1_filename.ext" => "prefix1",
     "prefix2_filename.ext" => "prefix2",
     "another_prefix_filename.ext" => "another_prexix",
   ]
>>> $arr3 = array_combine(array_values(array_sort(array_flip(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)))), array_values(array_sort(array_flip(array_intersect($arr2, $arr1)))));
=> [
     12 => "prefix1_filename.ext",
     34 => "prefix2_filename.ext",
   ]
```

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I need. Didn't need to sort the flipped arrays in the end. Thanks!

Comment: @JamieB for this example you don’t, but worth doing in case you get an array in a different order... it just ensures that the results from both will be the same order

Comment: Noted. For what it's worth, the two input arrays are sorted beforehand, in case that makes a difference?

Comment: That’s fine then, as long as you know the input is clean. I’ve worked with too many APIs in my time, I’ve grown to trust no one but myself haha

Answer (score 0):

note : $arr2 can't be compared because difference of array keys

```
 <?php
    $arr1 = array(12=> "prefix1",34 => "prefix2");

    $arr3 = array(12 => "prefix_filename.ext",
    34 => "prefix2_filename.ext"
    );

    $arr2 = array(
    "prefix_filename.ext" => "prefix",
    "prefix2_filename.ext" => "prefix2"
    );


    $result=array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: I've changed the inconsistencies of prefix/prefix1